# Flume: Bechmarking HTTP source & File channel

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

We have been trying to validate & benchmark the Flume performance for our production use.

We have configured Flume to have HTTP source, File channel & Kafka sink. 
Hardware : 8 Core, 32 GB RAM, CentOS6.5, Disk - 500 GB HDD.
Flume configuration:

```
svcagent.sources = http-source                                                                        
svcagent.sinks = kafka-sink1                                                                          
svcagent.channels = file-channel1

# HTTP source to read receive events on port 5005
svcagent.sources.http-source.type = http                                                              
svcagent.sources.http-source.channels = file-channel1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
svcagent.sources.http-source.port = 5005                                                              
svcagent.sources.http-source.bind = 10.15.1.31                                                        

svcagent.sources.http-source.selector.type = multiplexing                                             
svcagent.sources.http-source.selector.header = archival                                               
svcagent.sources.http-source.selector.mapping.true = file-channel1                                    
svcagent.sources.http-source.selector.default = file-channel1                                         
#svcagent.sources.http-source.handler =org.eiq.flume.JSONHandler.HTTPSourceJSONHandler                

svcagent.sinks.kafka-sink1.topic = flume-sink1                                                       
svcagent.sinks.kafka-sink1.brokerList = 10.15.1.32:9092                                              
svcagent.sinks.kafka-sink1.channel = file-channel1                                                   
svcagent.sinks.kafka-sink1.batchSize = 5000                                                                                                                                                                 

svcagent.channels.file-channel1.type = file                                                           
svcagent.channels.file-channel1.checkpointDir=/etc/flume-kafka/checkpoint                             
svcagent.channels.file-channel1.dataDirs=/etc/flume-kafka/data                                        
svcagent.channels.file-channel1.transactionCapacity=10000                                             
svcagent.channels.file-channel1.capacity=50000                                                        
svcagent.channels.file-channel1.checkpointInterval=120000                                             
svcagent.channels.file-channel1.checkpointOnClose=true                                                
svcagent.channels.file-channel1.maxFileSize=536870912                                                 
svcagent.channels.file-channel1.use-fast-replay=false
```

When we tried to stream HTTP data, from multiple clients (around 40 HTTP clients), we could get a max processing of 600  requests/sec, and not beyond that. Increased the XMX setting of Flume to 4096.

Even we have tried with a Null Sink (instead of Kafka sink). Did not get much performance improvements. So, assuming the blockage is the HTTP source & File channel.

Could you please suggest any fine tunings to improve the performance of this setup.

Comment: you can try to increase the size of the input message.

Comment: @vishnuviswanath, that's correct. But first, we would like to see to what max the Flume HTTP source can support. Later, we will work on the batching & adding multiple nodes.

Comment: ok. have you seen this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLUME/Flume+NG+Performance+Measurements .

Comment: we used to benchmark how many MBs of logs flume is able to save into HDFS per minute.

Comment: @vishnuviswanath, I saw the Flume benchmark link. It benchmarked the TCP & UDP sources, which would obviously give better throughput than the HTTP. What's your observation on Flume to HDFS performance per minute (on a typical 8 core 32 GB server) ?